# Can the opacity / translucence of an SVG group be adjusted together?

Tags: svg, transparency

I have an SVG "g" object that has several components.  I'd like to render the whole thing partly transparent (e.g. alpha = 0.5)  I'd also like to to be darker if possible.  I know individual fill colors can be adjusted, but how about all of them together, possibly in some parameters to the "g" (grouping) structure.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Changing the `opacity` of the `<g>` (either by the `opacity="..."` attribute, or the `opacity` CSS rule) will cause the contents of the group to first be composited and then the result to be lowered in opacity. Note that this is distinctly different from lowering the opacity on all the elements inside the group (which you can also do via CSS):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HZr7v/12/

[image]

Uses this SVG:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400">
    <defs><filter id="Darker">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="
       0.3  0   0   0   0
        0  0.3  0   0   0
        0   0  0.3  0   0
        0   0   0  0.8  0"/>
    </filter></defs>
    <g id="g1" transform="translate(60,60)"> <!-- top left -->
        <circle r="40" /><rect width="80" height="60" />
    </g>
    <g id="g2" transform="translate(220,60)"><!-- top right -->
        <circle r="40" /><rect width="80" height="60" />
    </g>
    <g id="g3" transform="translate(60,200)"><!-- bottom left -->
        <circle r="40" /><rect width="80" height="60" />
    </g>
    <g id="g4" transform="translate(220,200)"><!-- bottom right -->
        <circle r="40" /><rect width="80" height="60" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

…with this CSS:

```css
circle { fill:red }
rect { fill:blue }

#g2 * { opacity:0.5 }         /* Change the opacity of each shape    */
#g3   { opacity:0.5 }         /* Change the opacity of the group     */
#g4   { filter:url(#Darker) } /* Darkens and drops opacity for group */
```

Note in particular the difference in appearance where the circle and square overlap.

The `feColorMatrix` filter looks daunting. All it does is set the RGB values to each be 30% of the original RGB (i.e. darker), and the alpha to be 80% of the original alpha. Change the values as you see fit.

---

Oh, and if you want to desaturate also you can throw this into the filter (before or after the darken step):

```xml
<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0.5"/>
<!-- values="0"  will drop all color, leaving grayscale only -->
<!-- values="1"  will leave the current saturation color     -->
<!-- values="99" will super-saturate the colors              -->
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  Thank you!  The power of feColorMatrix is daunting.  It looks like you could hue shift by using a 3D rotation matrix.

Comment: @MattD yes, you can, but conveniently the spec allows a [`hueRotate` type built in](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement).

Comment: Unfortunately, the JSFiddle seems broken in Chrome, Ffx as of 2014/10/14 - add width="400" height="400" attributes to <svg> tag to make it show all 4 examples. Updated the fiddle to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could set opacity on the `<g>` itself and that would work. If you want it darker you'll need to apply a filter to the `<g>` something along these lines perhaps

```
    <filter id="Darker" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feFlood in="SourceGraphic" flood-color="#0f0" flood-opacity="0.5" result="img2"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="img2" mode="darken"/>
    </filter>
```

Comment: +1 for good information. Though I'm not sure that filter is exactly right; it leaves 50% green over all transparent areas and generally casts a green pall on the world. ;) See my answer for a different 'darker' filter.